# Sheets: Average range if other column cell contains substring

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a social media performance report in Google Sheets, and want to average the engagement rate % for posts that use a specific tag (as assigned in SproutSocial) in a central 'campaigns' sheet.

Here's an example of what the data looks like

```
Col A | Col B           | Col C
-------------------------------------
Reach | Engagement Rate | Tags
-------------------------------------
1200  | 3.4%            | Black Friday
480   | 1.3%            | Black Friday, Blog Post
480   | 3.1%            | Landing Page, Black Friday
480   | 5.6%            | Blog Post
```

So let's say I want to see the average Engagement Rate (ER%) for our Black Friday posts. So far, I've used this formula in the campaigns sheet:

```
=AVERAGEIF('Nov 2021'!$C:$C, "Black Friday", 'Nov 2021'!$B:$B)
```

This only does an exact match on column C, so returns 3.4% as there's only one matching post.

So, how do I match substrings? I've tried a RegexMatch on the AVERAGEIF criterion, but it returns zero results...

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcards:

```
=averageif(C:C,"*Black Friday*",B:B)
```

[image]